# Opens the appstore and not the app on the phone

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, deep-linking

the situation is this - I'm creating a deep link dynamically, and the user should get into another application on the phone. In fact, on Android, everything works fine. And on the iPhone, the browser opens with the "open" button, and when I click on it, I get into the appstore. Although the application should open. What is the problem?

I use fireabse. I installed team id, installed apple id

Here is what I did:
Added link type in xcode -> info -> URL Types
[image: URL types]

Added related domain -
[image: related domain]

The function I use to generate the deeplink -

```
getDynamicLink(String dynamicLinkODengi) async {
      final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
        link: Uri.parse(dynamicLinkODengi),
        uriPrefix: "https://ecocity.page.link",
        androidParameters:
            const AndroidParameters(packageName: "com.example.app.android"),
        iosParameters: const IOSParameters(bundleId: "com.atlas.ecoCity"),
      );
      final dynamicLink =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);
      return dynamicLink;
    }
```

The function through which I open the deep link -

```
_launchURL(URI link) async {
     if (await canLaunchUrl(link)) {
      
       await launchUrl(link, mode:
       LaunchMode.externalApplication);
     } else {
       throw 'Could not launch $link';
     }
   }
```

I repeat, I successfully open another application on android

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you using a universal link? Have you set up the associated domains and the apple app site association file?

Comment: @Paulw11 check, please